# What are some best books to start with that cover convergence, series, and so on?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, convergence-divergence

So far, I know how to differentiate, limits and a few other things.

At my college the teacher is talking about fundamental sequences, Cauchy, Raabe-Duhamel, D'Alembert, general criteria of convergence, Weierstrass...

Where can I start to really understand these topics well? Maybe a book or something? (Hint: I don't like those books with plenty of formulas and no practical examples).

Comment: Any introductory real analysis text should do. But be sure it's a "baby analysis" text, such as http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Introduction-Steven-R-Lay/dp/0131481010

Comment: On the web, http://www.mathcs.org/analysis/reals/ is a good place to start.

Comment: What does "s.o." in your title mean?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOTS of terrific real analysis textbooks out there,but it sounds to me like you want something with just the basics and lots of examples. There's no better book for that then Kenneth Ross' *Elementary Analysis:The Theory Of Calculus*. It's exactly what the title says it is and it's by a master analyst.There's no better book for a student beginning real analysis with a weak calculus background who needs to get up to speed, which sadly is all too common these days. 
Another book you could try which is very good for this,but considerably more difficult, is Michael Spivak's classic *Calculus*. Don't let the title fool you-this is a rigorous presentation of calculus with thorough discussions of convergence and limits. As I said,though-it's considerably harder then Ross,especially the exercises.